# Can I give a class name as an XML element?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm looking to use XML to fill in some definitions of objects. I really want the file to be able to give a class name in a property itself:

```xml
<Object>
  <Name>Something</Name>
  <ObjClass>SomeClass</ObjClass>
</Object>
```

where `SomeClass` is the name of a class defined in code somewhere else that gets instantiated when the file is deserialized (or the class is static, I haven't decided). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
// Deserialize your XML into an object variable called xmlObject, this assumes the XmlObject class is defined and the xmlObject is declared somewhere in scope

Object something = null;

if (xmlObject.ObjClass == "SomeClass")
{
    something = new SomeClass();  // Assumes SomeClass is defined somewhere in scope
}
else
{
    something = new OtherClass();  // Assumes OtherClass is defined somewhere in scope
}
```

If **SomeClass** and **OtherClass** are similar, considering use inheritance to define a class relationship, perhaps off a **BaseClass**.